# Is it required to offer at least a Nafl Namaz between a Qaza and a Farz Namaaz?

Tags: salat, salat-qada, nafl

I had heard that farz namaaz can't be offered directly after praying a qaza namaaz and vice-versa (i.e. qaza namaaz can't be offered directly after praying a farz namaaz). Either there has to be a time gap or Should offer Sunnah or Nafl namaaz (as per the timing of current salat) between performing qaza and farz namaaz.

Can someone shed some light and provide some info based on sunnah and ah-hadith to substantiate the claim?

Example:
- Can we offer Isha' Qaza namaaz after Fajr Farz namaaz?
- Can we offer any qaza namaaz after Asr?